# Updating old mySQL script

Tags: php, mysql, security, deprecated

I have an old script that simply inserts two sets of values into a database.
I've been told that there are new and better ways of doing this than that which i've used below, can anyone tell me what needs to change?

```
mysql_connect("server","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$datainsert = "INSERT INTO form1
        (name, message)
        VALUES
        ('$name',
        '$message_body')";

$result = mysql_query($datainsert);

if($result){
    header('Location: success.html');
} else{
    echo("<br>There was a problem.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace mysqL with mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("server","user","password", "database");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO form1 (name, message) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $message_body);
$stmt -> execute();
if($stmt) {
    header('Location: success.html');
} else {
    echo("<br>There was a problem.");
}
```

It uses MySQL Inproved, and it uses prepared statements (so SQL injections are made impossible).

Comment: You forgot an end bracket I think on line two, but thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just switch from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0):

Closest to existing code would be to use mysqli_*

***But*** please don't just add ***i*** and think your problems are solved. Use prepared statements, check out this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)